# How can I build dropbear in Cygwin? (or how can I convert my OpenSSH keys to dropbear)?

Tags: openssh

I'm trying to build dropbear in Cygwin.
I've downloaded the tar and extracted it but I'm unsure what to do next so would appreciate some help.

Alternatively, is there any way I can convert my existing OpenSSH keys to dropbear format?

Thanks

EDIT:
here's some additional info:

```
 $ cd dropbear-2013.58
 $ ./configure
    make
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
    checking for suffix of executables... .exe
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    configure: No $CFLAGS set... using "-Os -W -Wall" for GCC
    checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
    checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
    checking build system type... i686-pc-cygwin
    checking host system type... i686-pc-cygwin
    checking for ar... ar
    checking for ranlib... ranlib
    checking for strip... strip
    checking for install... install
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
    checking for ANSI C header files... yes
    checking for sys/types.h... yes
    checking for sys/stat.h... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... yes
    checking for string.h... yes
    checking for memory.h... yes
    checking for strings.h... yes
    checking for inttypes.h... yes
    checking for stdint.h... yes
    checking for unistd.h... yes
    checking whether __UCLIBC__ is declared... no
    checking for crypt in -lcrypt... yes
    checking for deflate in -lz... no
    configure: error: *** zlib missing - install first or check config.log ***
```

mingw64-i686-zlib.lst
mingw-zlib-devel.lst
mingw-zlib1.lst
zlib0.lst
are all installed so I'm not sure where the problem lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not installed `zlib-devel`. Open the setup and search for `zlib-devel`. `mingw-zlib-devel` are just for code written for MinGW.